# XHTML place div on bottom of page

Tags: xhtml, html

I have an XHTML with its content of unknown height.

I want to have a small text in a div that's always on the bottom of the browser viewport when the content is smaller than the height of the viewport and go under the viewport when the content is higher.

I can't do this with position:fixed and bottom:0 because if the content is higher it will overlap the content.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at [this example](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/css-fixed-footer.html). The code is [there](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/index.php/css-fixed-footer/).

Comment: Thanks, I did. It doesn't quite work as it should.

If I resize the browser it stops working.

Comment: @Francisc It works as expected with Safari. With which browser did you test?

Comment: Hey! I tried it with IE8.

It does as expected except when I restore the window and start playing with it's height.